# Getting multiple errors during Database-Migration with EF6 and .NET 4.6.1

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-migrations

Getting the following errors:

**"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." at line 89 of Configuration.cs**

Line 89 is simply a `context.SaveChanges();`, at the end of the class file:

```
namespace Model.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Model.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            SeedData.AdditionalSeed _AdditionalSeed = new SeedData.AdditionalSeed();

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_StateOrProvince(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_CountryOrRegion(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_ContactTypes(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_CurrencyCodes(context);

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_CalendarSettings_CalendarView(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_CalendarSettings_WeeklyView(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_CalendarSettings_WhatToShow(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_Calendar_FuturePastSettings(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_ItemsAndInventory_AdvancedInventory_Barcodes_CopyBarcodeFrom(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_ItemsAndInventory_UnitOfMeasureType(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_PayrollEmployees_EmployeeDefaults_PayFrequency(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_PayrollEmployees_EmployeeDefaults_SickAndVacationDefaults_AccuralPeriod(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_PayrollEmployees_EmployeeDefaults_Taxes_FilingStatus(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_ReportsAndGraphs_ReportPreferences_DatePreparedFormat(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_ReportsAndGraphs_ReportPreferences_PageNumberFormat(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_ReportsAndGraphs_ReportPreferences_PageLayout(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_SalesAndCustomers_InvoicePackingSlip(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_SalesAndCustomers_RoundingRules(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_SalesAndCustomers_Shippers(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_SalesTax_Intervals(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_SalesTax_SalesTaxCode(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_SendForms_SendMethod(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_SendForms_DeliveryMethod(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_SendForms_EmailTemplateCategoryList(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Preferences_TimeAndExpenses_WorkWeek(context);

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_RoleMaster(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_AccountingRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_BankingRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_CentersRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_CompanyRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_CustomerAndReceivablesRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_EmployeesAndPayrollRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_FileRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_ListsRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_ReportsRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_SiteSettingsRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_TimeTrackingRole(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Security_VendorsAndPayablesRole(context);

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_TaxesFilingStatus(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_EmploymentType(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_EmployeeEmergencyContactType(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_EmployeeEthnicity(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_EmployeeMaritalStatus(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Salutations(context);

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_DefaultUnitUsedForTypes(context);
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_UnitOfMeasureDefaultType(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_UnitOfMeasureDefaultBaseUnits(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_UnitOfMeasureDefaultRelatedUnits(context);
            context.SaveChanges();

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Terms(context);

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_TaxForms(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_TaxFormDetail(context);

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_AccountTypes(context);
            context.SaveChanges();

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_Industries(context);
            context.SaveChanges();

            _AdditionalSeed.Seed_OrganizationTypes(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

When I comment this line out I then get the following error:

**"Sequence contains more than one element" at line 12 of TaxFormDetail.cs**

The code for this class file is over 1200 lines so I will only supply the unique lines:

```
namespace Model.Migrations.SeedData
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class AdditionalSeed
    {
        public void Seed_TaxFormDetail(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            context.TaxFormDetail.AddOrUpdate(
                r => new { r.TaxFormID, r.TaxCodeLineDescription },
                new TaxFormDetailModel() { TaxCodeLineNumber = null, TaxCodeLineDescription = "Schedule F: Interest expense, mortgage", TaxFormID = context.TaxForms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.TaxForm.Equals("1040")).RecordID },
                .....
                new TaxFormDetailModel() { TaxCodeLineNumber = null, TaxCodeLineDescription = "Pt I-Unrel Bus Inc: Sch C, L3-Inc-real/pers prop", TaxFormID = context.TaxForms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.TaxForm.Equals("990-T")).RecordID }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My model for this table is as follows:

```
[Table(name: "TaxFormDetail")]
public class TaxFormDetailModel
{
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid RecordID { get; set; }

    public Guid TaxFormID { get; set; }

    public string TaxCodeLineNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string TaxCodeLineDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I have read numerous google and SO results on these errors and nothing helps unless I have missed something.

**EDIT**

The only error I have is the stack trace as this is run by the Package Manager, There is no other way I know of of getting anything else:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](DbSet`1 set, IEnumerable`1 identifyingProperties, InternalSet`1 internalSet, TEntity[] entities)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](IDbSet`1 set, Expression`1 identifierExpression, TEntity[] entities)
   at Model.Migrations.SeedData.AdditionalSeed.Seed_TaxFormDetail(ApplicationDbContext context) in Z:\_Profile Storage\Projects\Corporate.WEB\Model\Migrations\SeedData\TaxFormDetail.cs:line 12
   at Model.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) in Z:\_Profile Storage\Projects\Corporate.WEB\Model\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 81
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains more than one element
```

Comment: What's the inner exception? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities-mvcentity-frame/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround for this situation.

For the **"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." at line 89 of Configuration.cs** error, I changed the seed method to check for existing data for that specific table (tax code) and if the table was empty, add records **NOT** add or update.

As far as **"Sequence contains more than one element" at line 12 of TaxFormDetail.cs** goes, I basically did the same thing.

Now every time I do an Update-Database PM command, I do not get any more errors.